# Why I am getting this dependency error?

Tags: centos, yum

I try to install Shibboleth service provider to Centos 7. However,

I get this error:

```
Error: Package: shibboleth-2.5.3-1.1.x86_64 (security_shibboleth)
           Requires: libmemcached.so.2(libmemcached_2)(64bit)
Error: Package: shibboleth-2.5.3-1.1.x86_64 (security_shibboleth)
           Requires: libmemcached.so.2()(64bit)
```

I installed the 64 bit version but still I get this error why?

Comment: Do you have `libmemcached_2` 64-bits installed?

Comment: Installed Packages
libmemcached.x86_64                                                   1.0.16-3.el7                                                   
Available Packages
libmemcached.i686

Comment: How can I remove the libmemcached.i686 ?

Comment: Why you think you must remove it?

Comment: Idk actually =) I don't understand the problem. Package is already installed but still it says it is required.

Comment: May be it is not finding libmemcached package in your system.Where did you installed the libmemcached package in your system?